# Implement Classic Async Pattern using TPL

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, asynchronous, workflow-foundation-4, task-parallel-library

I'm trying to implement a custom TrackingParticipant for WF 4. I can write the Track method, but my implementation will be slow.

How can I implement the Begin/EndTrack overrides using .NET 4.0's Task Parallel Library (TPL)? I've looked at [TPL and Traditional .NET Asynchronous Programming](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997423.aspx) but am not sure how to apply it here.

Note that TrackingParticipant is part of .NET and has the Classic Async Pattern predefined using virtual methods.

```
public class MyTrackingParticipant : TrackingParticipant
{
    protected override IAsyncResult BeginTrack(
        TrackingRecord record, TimeSpan timeout,
        AsyncCallback callback, object state)
    {
        // ?
    }

    protected override void EndTrack(IAsyncResult result)
    {
        // ?
    }

    protected override void Track(TrackingRecord record, TimeSpan timeout)
    {
        // synchronous code to be called
    }
}
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This is the generic pattern with which to implement the classic APM programming model:

```
protected override IAsyncResult BeginTrack(TrackingRecord record, TimeSpan timeout, AsyncCallback callback, object state)
{
    Task result = Task.Factory.StartNew(
        (taskState) =>
        {
           // ... your async work here ...
        },
        state);

    if(callback != null)
    {
        result.ContinueWith((t) => callback(t));
    }

    return result;
}

protected override void EndTrack(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
{
   // Call wait to block until task is complete and/or cause any exceptions that occurred to propagate to the caller
   ((Task)asyncResult).Wait();
}
```

If the EndXXX method returned a result you would actually return the `Result` property of the `Task` instead of just calling `Wait`. For example:

```
protected override int EndAwesomeCalculation(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
{
   // This will block until the result is available and/or cause any exceptions that occurred propagate to the caller
   return ((Task<int>)asyncResult).Result;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! This works; oddly, the workflow still blocks until Track() completes. (It does call the Begin/End methods.) It looks like I'd have to implement a queue to get the behavior I want. (Not to detract from your correct answer!)