# handling exception in Tpl

Tags: c#, .net, exception, task-parallel-library

I have read a lot on how to handle exceptions in TPL but don't really understand.

Lets take this example code:

```
var task1 = new Task(() => { throw new Exception("Throw 1"); });
var task2 = task1.ContinueWith(t => Console.WriteLine("Catch 1:{0}", t.Exception.Message), 
                              TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnFaulted);
var task3 = task2.ContinueWith(t => Console.WriteLine("Continuation"));

task1.Start();
try {
    task1.Wait();
}
catch (Exception ex) {
    Console.WriteLine("Wait Exception: {0}", ex.Message);
}
```

I expected this to print

```
Catch 1
Continuation
```

But I get

```
Catch 1
Continuation
Wait Exception
```

This means that the exception is still considered unhandled when the task completes and the task finalizer will eventually tear down the application.

**How do I handle the exception inside the continuation so the finalizer will not throw?** At the same time I want the task to remain in the faulted state so wrapping the task in try/catch will not work.

---

The background is that I want to implement the async event pattern as specified [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5162147/157224) but with error handling. My complete code looks like this

```
public IAsyncResult Begin(AsyncCallback callback, object state, Action action) {
    var task1 = new Task(action);
    var task2 = task1.ContinueWith(t => HandleException(t.Exception), 
                                   TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnFaulted);
    if (callback != null) {
        var task3 = task2.ContinueWith(t => callback(t),
                                      TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
        var task4 = task3.ContinueWith(t => HandleException(t.Exception), 
                                       TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnFaulted);
    }

    task1.Start();

    return task;
}
```

Comment: I thought about calling `t.Wait()` in a try in the continuation and ignoring the exception. But that won't work, because the continuation may be executed after the other `Wait()` throws.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do your wait on the task that fails, and if you read the [documentation on Task.Wait](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd235635.aspx) carefully you will see that wait will rethrow the exception in this case.

But if you wait on your `task3` everything should work as expected.

Of course you should keep this in mind:

> When you use the OnlyOnFaulted option, it is guaranteed that the
>   Exception property in the antecedent is not null. You can use that
>   property to catch the exception and see which exception caused the
>   task to fault. If you do not access the Exception property, the
>   exception will go unhandled. Also, if you attempt to access the Result
>   property of a task that has been canceled or has faulted, a new
>   exception will be raised.

(Reference [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee372288.aspx))

And finally yet another good source on [How to handle exceptions thrown by tasks](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd537614.aspx)

I hope this helps.

Comment: I think I get it. Wait will always cause an exception even if I access the .Exception property. However, accessing .Exception changes the exception to not be "unhandled" so the task finalizer will not throw. A quick test seems to confirm exactly that. Thanks