# How to use the twitterService.BeginGetDirectMessage() method in tweetsharp with Wpf?

Tags: twitter, wpf-4.0, tweetsharp

Basically my requirement is getting all direct messages from `TweetSharp.dll` for a particular user, for the time being I'm getting this messages from following line of code:

```
string message = null;
List<string> messages = new List<string>();
IEnumerable<TwitterDirectMessage> directMessages = service.ListDirectMessagesReceived(new ListDirectMessagesReceivedOptions());

////Fetch all current direct message:
foreach (TwitterDirectMessage directMessage in directMessages)
{
    //Store each message into a list, in reverse older:
    message = /*"[" + directMessage.CreatedDate.ToString() + "]" +*/ directMessage.Text;
    messages.Insert(0, message);
}
```

But I want to use `twitterService.BeginGetDirectMessage` method to get all direct messages for particular user but problem is that how can get incoming new message. So let me know appropriate solution to solve this problem.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Tweetsharp is implementing an asynchronous programming model, check out this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5161159/implement-classic-async-pattern-using-tpl) Post or the [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd321416.aspx) on how to use Tasks to wrap asynch methods.